# Can I safely remove pre-installed software in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: software-center, uninstall, 13.10

I uses a lots of Google Apps Product in my Laptop, Tablet and Mobile. Since I never use all pre-installed software in Ubuntu, can I remove it?

E.g like:

- LibreOffice | I use Google Doc etc.
- RhythmBox | I use Google Play Music
- Thunderbird | I use Gmail, don't like client
- Videos | Watch online
- Messaging | Hangouts

And other softwares like Remmina Client, BitTorrent Client. Can I simply remove it in Ubuntu Software Centre? I like my Laptop clean and having unmessy software that I never use.

I normally use Chromium Browser to do all the stuff, I think I am heavy user of Google, and love the simplicity of Ubuntu. Lol! Can anyone tell or guide me? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Let me ask you one question: are you *google*? jk

Comment: Of course I Google it first "Lucio the funny man" ;) jk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other users already mentioned, the pre-installed applications like the one that you have mentioned are easy to uninstall.

Have in mind that whenever you want to uninstall any application, if this is just a utility for the user **and no other software depends upon this**, then you wont have any issue removing it from the system.

So the question that you have to ask your self is: **Does this application is useful directly or *indirectly*?** Then you choice :)

Comment: Okay then. Based on your knowledges and experiences, all applications that I've mentioned above affect the system issues or not if I uninstall it? Thanks

Comment: Not at all. Remove them if you want to. Maybe an example could help you: *unity* is pre-installed and it should not be removed, at least if you want to see a nice OS :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can "safely" uninstall any of the default programs that are shipped with Ubuntu - and it is easily done using the Ubuntu Software Center as you already suggested.

However, in my opinion it is a good idea to have a default application for the most basic tasks required on your computer, just in case your Google services cannot do anything for you online. If you go to System Settings > Details > Default Applications you can see the programs Ubuntu will open to do the most simple tasks on your computer. In case you don't like the programs shipped with Ubuntu you can do any replacement you like here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all aforementioned apps can be removed easily through USC or CLI.

Consider that some of mentioned apps you want to remove may be dependent on shared supporting files with different other apps.

I personally never remove any default app since you run a risk of damaging the system. Risk is bigger with some applications and lower with others, of course with some apps there is no risk at all, however I believe it is best to avoid the risk.

Ubuntu doesn't have pollution like win powered systems and unused apps do not make any difference on performance if not uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it may benefit others who see this, I would recommend that you make an Ubuntu install to a flash drive (Not a Live Installer, an actual install) and try deleting different programs on that to see if they effect any other parts of the system. This way, you have a harmless way to find out what can be easily removed.